# Using CompareTo to compare both a string and a double value within an array?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I am given an assignment to sort an array of inputted values using both insertion sort and selection sort. I am having some trouble with overwriting the `compareTo` method with in the `Item` class. I would like it to sort so that if two items are priced the same it then compares based on `Category`. So Child (C) items come first and then M and then Women. This is my code and every time that I attempt to compile it I get an error saying that `double` cannot be referenced.

```
public int compareTo (Object other) {
      int result;

      double otherPrice = ((Item)other).getClothPrice();
      String otherCategory = ((Item)other).getClothCategory();

      if (clothPrice == otherPrice)
         result = clothCategory.compareTo(otherCategory);
      else
         result = clothPrice.compareTo(otherPrice);

      return result;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

First, your `compareTo` method should take an `Item` as a parameter. If this results in a compiler error, make sure `Item` is implementing `Comparable<Item>`.

To compare primitive `double` values, use [`Double.compare`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#compare-double-double-):

```
public int compareTo(Item other) {
    int result = Double.compare(clothPrice, other.clothPrice);
    if (result == 0) {
        result = clothCategory.compareTo(other.clothCategory);
    }
    return result;
}
```

If you're using Java 8, you may prefer to use some of the more advanced features of [`Comparator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) which make extending this code much simpler:

```
private static final Comparator<Item> naturalOrdering = Comparator
        .comparingDouble(Item::getClothPrice)
        .thenComparing(Item::getClothCategory);

public int compareTo(Item other) {
    return naturalOrdering.compare(this, other);
}
```

Comment: I was forgetting to add the Comparable, thank you for that I ended up getting the code to work by just changing the else  to

   result = Double.compare(clothPrice, otherPrice); Would that accomplish the same thing?

Comment: @TommyHarvey Yes, that would accomplish the same thing. I've just rewritten your code in the way I've seen most people write it.

Comment: Ok thank you I was just going off the example we were given in class. Thank you very much for your help

Comment: Wow, I didn't know about `Comparator`. Thanks! Shouldn't that `Comparator` object be cached for the sake of performance rather than re-instantiated on each call to `compareTo`?

Comment: @BasilBourque Yes, it would be much more efficient to cache the `Comparator` object using a `static` field.